# Leaflet match label text color with object color

Tags: r, leaflet

I want the color of a label to match the color of the polygon. Here I'm using static labels, but I don't think that should matter. I found [this tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html) which can change the color of label text, but I want it to match the color palette used for the polygon. Here is a minimal example of my best attempt:

```
library(leaflet); library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc <- nc %>% st_transform(crs = 4326)
nc2 <- nc[1:3,]

pal <- colorFactor(c('red', 'green', 'blue'), domain = as.character(nc2$NAME))

leaflet(nc2) %>% 
  addPolygons(label = ~NAME,
              color = ~pal(NAME),
              labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, textOnly = T, textsize = 15, 
                                          style = list(
                                            color = ~pal(NAME)
                                          )))
```

[image]

So for example I want the text "Ashe" to be green. Is there a way to access variable names within `labelOptions`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hacky solution but it works. I loop over the rows of the data and use `addLabelOnlyMarkers` with the centroid of the row polygon, using `st_centroid`. I run the `pal` function at each iteration.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(nc2)) {
  text_col = pal(nc2$NAME[i])
  p <- p %>% 
    addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = st_centroid(nc2[i,]), 
                        label = ~NAME, 
                        labelOptions = labelOptions(
                            noHide = T, textOnly = T,
                            style = list('color' = text_col)
                        )
  )
}
```

I still welcome any better solution to this...